# Using xml input type to wcf webmethod

Tags: wcf

I'm quite new to wcf. I'm in the process of converting an .asmx service (methods only) to wcf service. I have 4 methods in the service class with farely simple parameters, but one of the methods has an xmldocument as parameter. Like:

```
public ServiceObject(xmldocument x, string y, ...){}
```

This parameter can of course not be serialized, and I get an error on this!

How do one come around this problem, or am I just using wcf the wrong way. When I outcomment the operationcontract in the interface the other methods with simple parameters run just fine.

Do I have to use properties or what...

Any help is appreciated, cheers Finn.

Comment: This has been an irk for a while, someone over at Pluralsight actually wrote a class that holds an XmlDocument and implements ISerializable, might be worth a look http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/keith/archive/2008/08/18/serializable-xmldocument.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service operation use an XElement instead of XmlDocument and then convert to an XmlDocument inside the operation if you need to